# Сообщить о не успешно завершенных задач Ansible

Tags: ansible, devops

Есть ли, переменная в Ansible, которая хранит в себе значения не успешно завершенных задач для каждого хоста?

Стоит задача слать оповещение в телеграм со списком хостов, где плейбук не отыграл до конца, а был завершен с ошибкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напишите свой callback, который будет обрабатывать `v2_playbook_on_stats`.

И внутри него отсылайте сообщение со списком хостов.

Для примера можете посмотреть плагин [notify_me](https://github.com/berlic/devopsdays-ansible/blob/master/callback_plugins/notify_me.py).
Подробное описание этого плагина есть [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/company/d2cio/blog/344046/).

Comment: Да, думаю нужно писать свое. Так и не нашел ничего готового, как раз есть резервное время.

Answer (score 0):

```
   **Можно добавить task который будет отправлять сообщение в api**
```

*Пример*

```
- name: 'ALARM TELEGRAM'
  uri:
    url: 'https://bot_telegram.ru/api'
    method: POST
    body: '{{system_fail_massage}}'
  when: 'build_system_fail'
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не подойдет к той структуре которая у моего проекта. По умолчания плейбук прерывается в случае любой ошибки и если такс будет конечным до него просто не дойдем очередь.